# Shortest path to loading an FBX sphere model into CDXUTSDKMesh or similar

Tags: direct3d, mesh, fbx, dxut

I'm porting some old XNA code to D3D11, and it uses FBX models.  They're pretty basic so I could re-create them in 3DSMax if needed, or convert if a tool exists.

All I want is to be able to get the mesh loaded, ideally along the lines of CDXUTSDKMesh (but that doesn't support FBX).  I looked at the Content Exporter but it still requires the FBX SDK installed, and I'm hoping to avoid that.

Is there a reasonably simple way to load an FBX mesh, or can I use 3DSMax to export to a format that -will- load via CDXUTSDKMesh.

What confuses me is that if you -create- a scene in Visual Studio via Item->New, it's a FBX model, which from what I can tell is completely unsupported without doing it yourself with the FBX SDK.

There must be a simpler way!  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Working with `.FBX` files is done with the Autodesk FBX SDK. The Visual Studio content pipeline is using the Autodesk FBX SDK: it installs the Autodesk FBX DLLs. The [Content Exporter](https://github.com/walbourn/contentexporter) also needs the Autodesk FBX DLLs.

Generally speaking, `FBX` is an authoring and interchange format. Games and 3D applications don't load FBX models directly, and instead load some runtime format along the lines of `VBO`, `SDKMESH`, or `CMO`--see the[DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh/wiki/Geometry-formats) wiki page on these formats. The developer needs the Autodesk FBX SDK on their build system, but they don't need to deploy it because their content is already 'cooked' into other binary formats.

The easiest thing for you to do is for you to add your FBX to Visual Studio, enable the content pipeline in your project, and then load the built `CMO` using [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/)--which can also load `VBO` or `SDKMESH` files, and is intentionally designed to be much like the XNA Game Studio class design but in C++.

If you are making a Digital Content Creation (DCC) application that needs to do direct I/O on FBX files, then you should use the Autodesk FBX SDK.